# Microsoft SQL Server Table Partitions on Distinct character values

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, data-partitioning

I am creating a partition table using some very specific character values.

If new rows aren't inserted that match any of the values in the partition function, I want it to go in the default partition .

Right now it's going in the default partition.

For example

if i have values of 'apple' , 'banana', 'cake';

and a new record is insert with a value of 'berry'

it gets assigned to the 'banana' partition.

HOw can I say that my partition values must be exact?

Comment: You can't with arbitrary strings. The partitioning function accepts **range** boundaries. If you want a dedicated partition assign each of these known values ( 'apple' , 'banana', 'cake') an integer (1,2,3) and partition on the integer code. As you are using a discrete datatype with no gaps each "special" value will get its own partition (make sure you allocate one at the end for higher values)

Comment: thanks, that what I was afraid of. I'll set up my demo with a lookup table the maps the strings to ints. The only reason I didn't want to do that was I was hoping to make incremental changes to the process as there are other loading data dependencies. But the best option would to have a numeric key anyways.